# How can I intergrate my backend API with my react app

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a react app and I have a ready made API but I have no idea to integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate backend by making network calls to your api

```
// Step 1 - import the necessary packages
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {
// Step 2 - declare useState hook with inital data as a empty array
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

// Step 3 - Make a asynchronus call to fetch the data from api
  const fetchDataFromApi = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://yourapi.com/data`);
        setData(response.data);
    }

// Step 4 - call the fetchDataFromApi function indide useEffect so that its called when componeent is mounted
 useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataFromApi();
  }, []);

// Step 5 - Map the data inside your markup
  return (
  <div>
    {data && data.map(items =>
      <div key={items.id}>{items.name}</div>
    )}
  </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

And don't forget to install axios by running the command npm i axios

Answer (score 0):

In your react component where you need the API data, you can implement a method for the API call e.g. `updateData() {}` which you then call on `componentDidMount()` and/or `componentDidUpdate()`

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      this.updateData();
   }

   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      // Do something with the props and call
      this.updateData();
      // if needed
   }

   updateData() {
      let api_url = ''; // dynamic url - depends on the state?
      fetch(api_url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                // Do something with the API data
                // this.setState({ data } )
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // handle the error appropriately
            });
   }
}
```